# Prolog: Increment value in list using nth1/3

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to implement a recursive Prolog predicate that when given a all 0 list `ResultList` with `Dim` elements and another list with values up to `Dim`, it runs trough this second list and increments +1 to the nth Element of `ResultList` and returns ResultList, so far I have:

```
increment_list([],_).
increment_list([Element|Tail],ResultList):-
    nth1(Element,ResultList,_ is _+1),
    increment_list(Tail,ResultList).
```

So for example

```
?-increment_list([1,2,4,3,4],[0,0,0,0]).
```

Would return:

```
[1,1,1,2]
```

What I'm apparently having difficulty and confusion is how to increment the value, is it possible to do it without defining an extra predicate or having a singleton Variable?

Comment: No, it isn't possible to do it without defining an extra predicate, although the [lambda](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=lambda) library probably would make it easier. The idea of sticking `_ is _+1` inside a call to `nth1/3` is definitely not going to work. Remember that Prolog is going to _unify_ these values, not compute them; `is/2` will perform arithmetic, but this expression wouldn't make sense much of anywhere because you are discarding the result of the addition. Also keep in mind Prolog is not going to evaluate expressions in-place. This is a core difference of Prolog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In prolog you cannot modify the value inside a list. You can do something like this:

```
increment_list([],L,L).
increment_list([H|T],LT,LO):-
    increment_nth(H,1,LT,LT1),
    increment_list(T,LT1,LO).

increment_nth(_,_,[],[]).
increment_nth(I,I,[H1|T1],[H2|T1]):-!, 
    succ(H1,H2).
increment_nth(I,C,[H|T1],[H|T2]):-
    C1 is C+1,
    increment_nth(I,C1,T1,T2).
```

Is basically a nested loop. In each loop you create a new list, which is the same previous list except the value at the index you consider which is the previous index incremented by one.

```
?- increment_list([1,2,4,3,4,1],[0,0,0,0],LO).
LO = [2, 1, 1, 2]
```

EDIT

Thanks to Daniel Lyons, i've modified the predicate.

Comment: Your `increment_list/3` is totally unnecessary, you can just remove it and rename `increment_list_/3` to `increment_list/3`. Also, I would suggest `succ/2`: `succ(I,I1),  succ(H1,H2)`; this predicate has the advantage that it can increment as well as decrement and helps making predicates with other call patterns. Good solution though! +1

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the `increment_nth`, particularly the `I1 is I+1` , `H2 is H1+1` and the `C1 is C+1`, where are we exactly incrementing the final list? let's say I would like it to decrement, instead of incrementing it, where would I I change it I assume it's the `H1`  ?

Comment: @spacing you cannot mutate a variable in Prolog. What makes `increment_nth/4` work is what's happening in the 4th argument where `H2` and `T2` wind up. You can think of that as the return path for this predicate, although this is just a convention here, not required by the language.

Comment: The latest revision damiano added cleared my confusion I was able to figure it out after the last edit! Thank you!!